# Apache2 and CakePHP project server deployment

Tags: php, bash, apache, cakephp, apache2

Hi my CakePHP project works fine. I have pushed it to my server @www.zeyeland.com/register. So the cake app works great but I am not sure how to get my Apache2 server to run the app automatically. I have to log into my server and type bin/cake server to start it.

Some time ago, When I uploaded my NodeJS app to server I had to edit the .bashrc file and use the bash script command "cd/var/www/html/zeyeland-website/bin && pm2 start npm1 -- start and cd". This command starts my nodejs app automatically

Do I need a similar bash command with bin/cake server to run my Cakephp project automatically too?

Comment: To be clear I trying to figure out how to run my cake app automatically. I know nodejs apps use npm and pm2. What is the syntax to get my cake app running on Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for upstarting apache and mysql so that whenever your server reboots the services will start automatically.

Look for upstart at

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples

Comment: Thanks, this article taught me a lot. I needed up being able to run a bash script on start up. Doing so did fix my problem though. Ultimately I had to do some major configuring to my virtual host file